# How to center menu in wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am not 100% sure about my code. I hope it's right and if resolved it will help others. I have created a menu to be placed in wordpress page, the menu is for some reason aligned left. I can't make the menu to be in the middle (center) of the page. Any insights?
HTML code is:

```
<p class="online"><a href="../home">Home </a>/
<a href="../about">About Us</a>/
<a href="../forums">Forums</a>/
<a href="../community">Community</a>/
<a href="../hotel">Hotel</a>/
<a href="../contact us">Contact</a>
</p>
```

The CSS code is:

```
.online a {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: inline-block;
}
.online a:link {
    color: #0000EE;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.online a:visited {
    color: #4c2c92;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.online a:hover {
    color: #2e8aca;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: did you try centering the `p` itself? your css deals with the `a`s inside it but not the paragraph itself

Answer (score 3):

Add "text-align:center;" to ".online"

```
.online {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the missing piece!